# Message sent without sound (silently) in Pyrogram — how to determine?

Tags: notifications, silent, mute, pyrogram

The is no flag/attribute in Pyrogram if the message was sent silently.
How to get it for incoming message?
Official Telegram Api: https://core.telegram.org/constructor/messageService

Tried to check all documentation, git repo an issues, but didn't find an answer